# fadeIn on scroll on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, scroll

jQuery fadeIn on scroll not working on iOS devices, but it works on windows, mac and android?

I guess it has something to do with iPhones capturing scroll events differently, but how do i fix this, so it either works on all devices, or just removes the .hideme class on scolling divs, if it's on an iPhone/iPad?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){
    
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){
            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#container
{
    height:2000px;    
}

#container DIV
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:lightgreen; 
}

.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    
</div>
```

[fiddle with same content as snippet above:](https://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/)

Answer (score 0):

Try without 'each' event.

`$(document).ready(function() {`

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(e){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    });
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wont work on windows then (havnt checked androind, mac or iOS with it though - but i bet that will be the same)

https://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/7431/

Comment: Soory. Change $(this) on $('.hideme')

Comment: Then it all fades in on the same time when you reach the first element, instead of fading in when you reach (each) element

Answer (score 0):

I never seemed to find a good solution, so i removed the fade on mobile device.

I changed my way of animating, and used AOS.js (AnimateOnScroll) which had a function of disabling the animations on mobile and ipad devices.